# How can I display the image to the desired product category? (if there are two separate models (Product and Image))

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

I can't figure out how to connect two models (product and images) in views and output images in html.

At the moment, several images are loaded for a specific project (for example, photos of a 3D model) all this through the admin panel. There are several projects, that is, 3D models, engineering and so on. And now I can't display 1 of those uploaded images on my site for each product (project). That is, either all the images that were uploaded are displayed (both 3d models and books and engineering).

Or if you use model.objects.first () displays the very first uploaded image( that is, the same for all projects).

My models:

```
 class Portfolio (models.Model):
        modeling='Modeling'
        books ='Books'
        engineering='Engineering'
        category_ch = [
            (modeling, 'Modeling'),
            (books, 'Books'),
            (engineering, 'Engineering'),
        ]
        category = models.CharField('Category',max_length=100,choices=category_ch, default=modeling)
        name = models.ForeignKey (Teams, related_name='maked', on_delete=models.PROTECT,blank=True)
        short_discription = models.CharField("Name of the work", max_length=200, blank=True)
        discription = models.TextField('Discription', blank=True)
        сustomer = models.CharField('Customer', max_length=100, default='Заказчик')
        created = models.DateTimeField('Date',auto_now_add=True)
        class Meta:
            verbose_name= 'Portfolio'
            verbose_name_plural = 'Portfolios'
        def __str__(self):
            return self.short_discription
        #def get_absolute_url(self):
            #return reversed ('shop:product_detail', args=[self.category.slug, self.slug]')
    
    class Image(models.Model):
        image = models.ImageField('Picture of work', upload_to='products/%Y/%m/%d', blank=True)
        product = models.ForeignKey(Portfolio, default=None, related_name='image', on_delete=models.PROTECT)
```

`Views`:

```
def portfolio_page(request):
    portfolio = Portfolio.objects.all()
    image_work= Image.objects.all()
    ctx = {
        'portfolio': portfolio,
        'image':image_work,
    }
    return render(request, 'mainApp/portfolio_page.html',ctx)
```

`HTML`:

```
{% for el in portfolio %}
                    <div class="portfolio_db">
                        <h3> {{ el.short_discription }} </h3>
                        {% for i in image %}
                            <img class="photo_work" src="{{ i.image_work }}" alt="Oh, there is something wrong here" width="155px" height="215px"></img>
                        {% endfor %}
                        <h4> Maked by {{ el.name }} </h4>
                        <h4> Ordered by {{ el.сustomer }} </h4>
                    </div>
                {% endfor %}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can enumerate over the `el.image_set.all` in the template, so:

```
{% for el in portfolio %}
    <!-- … -->
    {% for i in el.image_set.all %}
        <img class="photo_work" src="{{ i.image.url }}" alt="Oh, there is something wrong here" width="155px" height="215px"></img>
    {% endfor %}
    <!-- … -->
{% endfor %}
```

in the view, we can boost performance by fetching all related `Image`s and do the JOINing at the Django/Python layer:

```
def portfolio_page(request):
    portfolio = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related('image_set')
    ctx = {
        'portfolio': portfolio
    }
    return render(request, 'mainApp/portfolio_page.html',ctx)
```

Comment: Yea, maybe it will work, but the browser gives me an error:  
"Cannot find 'image_set' on Portfolio object, 'image_set' is an invalid parameter to prefetch_related()" and if i change in views "portfolio = Portfolio.objects.prefetch_related('image')" because in model "related_name='image' ", so then no pictures are shown at all in a page

Comment: @IvanW: if you change it to `related_name='image'`, then you access it with `el.image.all` (so you need to update the template), and in the `prefetch_related` you use `.prefetch_related('image')`

Comment: It however makes no sense to use a singular name for the `related_name`, since it is a *collection* of `Image`s, not a single `Image`.

Comment: I am very grateful for your help! Thank you :) It works. Only in the img tag,  need to change:{{i.image.url}}